# Is it mandatory to wait 6 months after I-140 approval to change Employers?

Tags: usa, greencard, h1-visa

I am currently working in H1B VISA. My current employer applied Employer based Green card for me in EB3 and it was got approved in July-2016. My current H1B reaches 6years at the end of 2017. My current client is offering full time position. I have below questions related to changing employers.

I heard a candidate has to stay minimum 6 months with the company which initiated Green card before switching Employees.

Is it mandatory to stay 6 months with the Employer who initiated Green Card?

Comment: When was the I-485 adjustment of status application filed? The rule is that you can change employers without redoing anything if the I-485 has been pending for 180 days.

Comment: @Dennis: OK. My I-485 has not filed. My Green Card is applied in EB3 and I-140 approved in July-2016.